# Did both Crocodile and Smoker use the artificial rain powder in Alabasta?

Tags: one-piece

By reading the manga and rewatching the anime I reached to this conclusion - 
Rain didn't fall in Alabasta for 3 years, but before that it did only in the capital and not in the neighbouring regions. 
When the artificial rain powder is used, the location where it is used gets more than average rain and nearby areas don't get any. 
Since by good faith we know the king wasn't using the powder or had any knowledge of it being used, could it be that Crocodile was using it in the capital from some hidden location which resulted in such a phenomenon and after he stopped using it, say the 3 years that no rain happened was the time natural weather was reconstructing itself and whether or not Crocodile was defeated, it would have rained nonetheless??

And secondly if Smoker had used artificial rain machine from a ship after the fight (couldn't figure out whether it was the case or not as he says when asked, he will never break the law but it is shown such a ship is there in the back) , how was he able to make rain the whole island??

Answer (score 2):

No, only Crocodile used the rain powder. Smoker was specifically asked by Hina if he used the dance powder and he said no (chapter 212). I know you stated this but it's firm proof until it's said otherwise.

Comment: If smoker would have said that he used the powder, he would be in offense and should be arrested, that's why he said no, it's heavely implied that he did use rain powder

Comment: He's known hina for a long time I don't think he would lie and I don't think they would arrest him.  Where is it heavily implied he did?

Comment: I absolutely agree with this answer and Rinne's comments. Smoker is an honest, straightforward marine. In the same chapter (212), he tells the marine main base that Tashigi is crying, that they could not defeat B.W. and that they should go to hell with the promotion they promise him. Being that direct to his own bosses, I can't imagine he would have any reason to lie to HIna.

Answer (score 2):

Crocodile had been using the rain powder to control the climate and preventing rain from falling in the kingdom, whilst making it seem the capital was using the rain powder to monopolize the rains. Crocodile admits to this when taunting Koza in chapter 197.

Later, with both Crocodile defeated and the rain maker ship captured, the rain started falling once more.

It's not made clear if Smoker used the rain powder or not, and I don't have access to the original japanese text, but checking the narration from chapter 212, on both internet scanlations and my brazilian edition of One Piece, both imply that the rain that fell on the kingdom was the natural bounty that could finally rain since nothing was preventing it anymore. So it can be understood that Smoker did not use the rain powder to cause the rain.